# C++ Iterator randomly gets invalidated

Tags: c++, function, iterator, call, invalidation

I'm lost: An iterator of a vector of std::string works perfectly unless there is a function call (Z_UB->set() ) before it++. Here's the code:

```
std::vector< std::string >::iterator it = g_SPP.scenarios->getVector().begin();
std::cout << "begin of vector: " << *it << std::endl;
Z_UB->set("s1", "scn2", 350);
it++;
std::cout << "second of vector: " << *it << std::endl;
```

creates the following output

```
begin of vector: scn1
```

However, if I move the function call like this:

```
std::vector< std::string >::iterator it = g_SPP.scenarios->getVector().begin();
std::cout << "begin of vector: " << *it << std::endl;
it++;
std::cout << "second of vector: " << *it << std::endl;
Z_UB->set("s1", "scn2", 350);
```

The result is the following, which is the expected behaviour:

```
begin of vector: scn1
second of vector: scn2
```

Inside the Z_UB->set() function there is nothing left but the call itself:

```
void Parameter::set( std::string _i, std::string _j, float value) {
//int i = indexSets[0]->backIndex(_i);
//int j = indexSets[1]->backIndex(_j);

//data2D[0][0] = value;
}
```

So if I call the Z_UB->set() function after I created the iterator, accessing it will crash the program. Is there anything vital that I missed about Iterators?

Comment: There's not enough information here to diagnose your specific problem.  Iterators do not get invalidated "randomly", so the problem is in your code but its not clear from this post _where_ in your code the problem lies.  Is `Z_UB` really of type `Parameter`?  Are there any other types it could be, anything that modifies the underlying `vector`?  `vector` iterators are invalidated during resizing of the `vector`'s internal storage.

Comment: Does getVector() return a reference to the vector, or a copy?

Comment: It returns a copy of the vector (in terms of I didn't use the & anywhere)

Comment: As it turned out, @Bo Persson had the right hint! Returning copies of the vector object doesn't make sense at this point. It works like a charm now. Thanks guys, I learned a great deal today!

Comment: I tried to answer my own question, but without enough reputation, I can't :). Anyone, please either answer my question and I'll mark it as correct or I have to wait 6 hours to answer my own question.

Comment: @BoPersson: post this as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.getVector() returned a copy of the vector. Comparing an iterator to the end point of the iterator of a completely different object doesn't make sense. Returning a reference solved the problem.

@Xeo also pointed out a much better explanation: When creating an iterator from a copy like this:

```
std::vector< std::string >::iterator it = g_SPP.scenarios->getVector().begin();
```

the copy immediately is destroyed thus invalidating the just created iterator. So the iterator shouldn't have returned the first element in the first place, but I can merely guess that this is hidden deeply in the implementation of the compiler.

Comment: It's also that the returned copy is immediatly destroyed at the end of the line where you create the iterator, as such the iterator gets immediatly invalidated and you entered the area of undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

If `g_SPP` is a *global* variable then iterators over it will be invalidated by any mutating operation.

---

**Update** -- this is from the 1998 ISO/ANSI spec:

The following invalidate all references, iterators, and pointers referring to elements of the sequence if an allocation is required.  An allocation is required if the current `capacity()` is less than the target vector size.

- `void reserve(size_type n)`
- `iterator insert(iterator position, const T& x)`,
- `void insert(iterator position, size_type n, const T& x)`,
- `void insert(iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last)`, and

Erasure invalidates all references, iterators, and pointers referring to elements after the position of the initial erased element.

- `iterator erase(iterator position)`
- `iterator erase(iterator first, iterator second)`

Resizing a vector is equivalent to calling either `insert` or `erase`.  According to 23.2.4.2/6: `resize(sz, c=value_type())` has the same effect as:

```
if (sz > size())
    insert(end(), sz - size(), c);
else if (sz < size())
    erase(begin() + sz, end());
else
    ;
```

Comment: interesting, could you add a reference backing this please?

Comment: By mutating do you mean addition and removal of elements only?

Answer (score 2):

Several possibilities:

- Either you do not have a good reproductible example: maybe in your first run you had only one element in your vector (how is it filled?), and invoked undefined behaviour because you did not check `it` against `g_SPP.scenarios->getVector().end()`
- Or `Z_UB->set` does not do what you think. Is it a polymorphic class? Is `set` virtual? Is the `->` operator overloaded?
- Is your app multithreaded and another thread is mutating your container?

Comment: the ->set function is overloaded but I added some debugging output to all the other versions. Only the one that I expected to run was invoked.

Answer (score 1):

a `std::vector<T>::iterator` will be invalidated if you add or remove elements while iterating over it, if the vector needs to resize itself internally, when an element is added.